# Virtual infiniband on kvm/qemu or another open source platform?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, infiniband

Is there any way to set up a virtual infiniband network within kvm/qemu?  If not, is there a viable open source alternative which would allow virtual infiniband networking?

(Note that I'm not looking to give VMs access to a physical IB network, I'm looking to have an entirely virtual IB network with no IB hardware)

Answer (score 2):

One of the following two drivers is probably what you are looking for: softRoCE (rdma_rxe) or softiWARP (http://www.gitorious.org/softiwarp). The softRoCE driver went upstream in Linux kernel version v4.8.

Comment: Do either of those give you an actual 'ifconfig ib0' type of network interface?

Comment: Since both run on top of Ethernet you won't need an equivalent of ib_ipoib. However, both drivers create RDMA interfaces that show up in the output of RDMA tools like e.g. ibv_devices.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, to the best of my knowledge, QEMU/KVM can only emulate the basic (but enought to run a VM) set of bios/video/usb/disk/net combo.
I know you said you don't want physical hardware, but your best chance at giving a VM some IB capabilities is using PCI passthrough.